# Clearification: Would an Observable notify onComplete() after it calls onError()?

Tags: rx-java, reactivex

I need to release resources when a stream is finished, either onError or onComplete. Reading from the [ReactiveX The Observable Contract](http://reactivex.io/documentation/contract.html) on Notification it saids

> An Observable may make zero or more OnNext notifications, each
>   representing a single emitted item, and it may then follow those
>   emission notifications by either an OnCompleted or an OnError
>   notification, but not both.

Am I correct to put the cleanup call in both onError and onComplete notification? like so:

```
.subscribe(
    //onNext
    completable -> Log.d(LOG_TAG,"done"),
    //onError
    throwable -> {
      Log.d(LOG_TAG,"error");
      serviceCleanup();
    },
    //onComplete
    this::serviceCleanup
);
```

eg. just for future documentation purposes so I can explain it to others, and myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should better use either [doFinally](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#doFinally-io.reactivex.functions.Action-) or [doAfterTerminate](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#doAfterTerminate-io.reactivex.functions.Action-) for resources cleaning up.